# Put One Image over other Image

Tags: html, css, image

I want to put one Image over other Image.

Following is my code :

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img id="image1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgg87.png" />
    <img id="image2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Jpc.png" />            
</div>
```

css :

```
#image1
{    
    top: 0; left: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#image2
{
    position:relative; left:-70;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/r5JMM/)

I want that when I make width or height increase of second image it also increase of first automatically. I want to put image 2 over image 1.

Any Guidance Please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r5JMM/1/ ? but I didn't got this part "*I want that when I make width or height increase of second image it also increase of first automatically.*"

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Also want to increase size of image 1 when it increase size of image 2 or it will be set it's size as of image 1. Means image 1 should be work as container.

Comment: done it, thank you sir. Your code help me, http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/r5JMM/2/

Comment: new updated code : http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/r5JMM/3/ I want something like this.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Sir, is it possible to do this using only div ? without img.

Comment: You can use multiple background images

Answer (score 0):

You may use **margin-left** in `#image2`

```
 #image1 {    
     top: 0; left: 0;
     position:relative;
     z-index:2; }
 #image2 {
     position:relative; left:-70px;
     z-index:1;
     margin-left: 25px;
 }
```

Comment: Sir, is it possible to do this using only div ? without img.

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5JMM/5/ for your answer

```
#image1{position:absolute;}
#image2{position:absolute;resize:both;}
.container{position:relative;}

<div class="container">
    <img id="image1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgg87.png" />
    <img id="image2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Jpc.png" />            
</div>
```

You can use jquery resize for doing resize operations on images